# Capturing group does not work with NSRegularExpression

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to make `NSRegularExpression` working with capturing group pattern. I've got string `abc{=2}` and regular expression pattern `{(.+)}` to get `=2` string but every attempt to create `NSRegularExpression` instance ends with

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" UserInfo=0x7fad7253cb40 {NSInvalidValue={(.+)}})
```

Code:

```
var error: NSError?
let regexp = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "{(.+)}", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
println("error = \(error)")
```

I cannot find what's wrong with this pattern. I am using regex101.com page and it works there.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

I see that escaping curly brackets (`\\{(.+)\\}`) solves problem with error but then I've got `{=2}` instead of `=2`.

Comment: Your answer should work. But it's not as standard. Many languages etc don't even let you do lookarounds, but most allow capture groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of `NSRegularExpression` and perhaps more so `NSTextCheckingResult`. Your captured range is actually the range at index `1` of your `NSTextCheckingResult` result instance.

An example:

```
let rx = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\{(.+?)\\}", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
let str = "abc{=2}"
let strRange = NSMakeRange(0, count(str))

rx.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: nil, range: strRange, usingBlock: { result, flags, stop in
    if let range0 = result?.range {
        println( (str as NSString).substringWithRange(range0) ) // "{=2}"
    }
    if let range1 = result?.rangeAtIndex(1) {
        println( (str as NSString).substringWithRange(range1) ) // "=2" <-- this is what you want!
    }
})
```

For each `NSTextCheckingResult` instance, the range at index `0` is a range representing the capture of your entire pattern (the `range` property is a shortcut for index 0). Your captures groups' ranges are held at indexes `1` and beyond. [From the NSTextCheckingResult docs `rangeAtIndex:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextCheckingResult/rangeAtIndex:):

> A result must have at least one range, but may optionally have more (for example, to represent regular expression capture groups).

The simplest way of understanding this is to imagine you provided a regex pattern with no capture groups. What would matched and represented by an `NSTextCheckingResult` instance? The entire matched pattern!

It would be good practice to use [NSTextCheckingResult's `numberOfRanges` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextCheckingResult/numberOfRanges) to make sure you have more than 1 range captured before you try to access your capture group's range. If you are using one capture group, you should expect `numberOfRanges` to be 2 if your capture group finds a match.

Finally, although this was not necessary, I added the `?` modifier to your capture group `(.+)` to make `(.+?)`. Your pattern was originally greedy inside the capture group, and the `?` makes the pattern non-greedy. I find non-greedy to be more predictable in general when working with regular expressions.

---

I should also mention the reason your solution works (with the result at index 0). By using the lookahead/lookbehind, you have effectively excluded the `{}` braces from your pattern completely. If you check your result, you should see that your capture group result actually exists at index 1 (but gives the same result as index 0).

Comment: Thanks, spent a while combating this with ghetto range offsets.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using different pattern. I don't know now if regex101.com matches it wrongly and correct match for my pattern is `{=2}` instead of '=2'.

I used positive lookbehind and positive lookahead to match this. This is the pattern:

`(?<=\\{)(.+)(?=\\})`